# How do I create a new view from an existing view using ECMAScript?

Tags: javascript, view

I wrote a script with ECMAScript to create a new calendar view with a click of the button by using:

this.viewCollection.add(viewInfo);

However, I'm wondering if it is possible to create the view based on an existing view so that all the view fields information can be carried over (scope, filters...)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [SP.View.viewQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee547992.aspx) property to fetch the query of the existing view.

And assign that query to the new view by using the [SP.ViewCreationInformation.query](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee547514.aspx) property.

Example:

```
viewInfo.set_query(yourOriginalView.get_viewQuery());
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to copy most of the properties from an existing view, but it's going to be a three step process:

1. Get the exiting [View](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.view_members.aspx)
2. Fill out properties available in the [ViewCreationInformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.viewcreationinformation_members.aspx) and create the view
3. Update the propertites of the new View which wasn't available in ViewCreationInformation and update the View

Comment: ... and two calls to the server.